# Get user by id with an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to determine if a given user ID is in a set of pre-defined accepted IDs. So far I have the following, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  if ((is_category(4) && $user_id == (array(16,19,73)))
  ...
?>
```

Comment: "What's wrong in my code"... I don't know, you tell us.  What *is* wrong?  What's the problem?  What are you trying to do?  What's happening?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use PHP's [in_array function](https://www.php.net/in_array)

Your code will look more like this:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ((is_category(4) && in_array($user_id, array(16,19,73)))
....
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as I want. Sorry if I don't explained well my problem. I thought is clear viewing code.